# WCF wsHttpBinding Client Certificate Authentication without using store in client

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, client-certificates, wshttpbinding

I have a WCF service registered as such using wsHttpBinding it is hosted in IIS with HTTPS binding to a valid and active certificate:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert, SslRequireCert"/>
      <authorization>
        <add users="*" accessType="Allow" />
      </authorization>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="https" binding="wsHttpBinding" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyNameSpace.WebService_TransportSecurity">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyNameSpace.WebService_Behaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck" />
            </clientCertificate>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="MyNameSpace.WebService" behaviorConfiguration="MyNameSpace.WebService_Behaviour">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="MyNameSpace.WebService_TransportSecurity"
                  contract="MyNameSpace.IMyServiceContract">
        </endpoint>

        <endpoint address="mex"
                             binding="mexHttpsBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I'm using .NET 4 so as far as I can tell this is the only binding that works with SSL and client certificate authentication.

I've generated the standard proxy using svcutil and trying to set the certificate (self signed that is also in the server) using it's base64 representation:

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(System.Convert.FromBase64String("thebase64ofthecertificate"));
if (certificate == null)
{
    return null;
}
IMyServiceContractClient client = new IMyServiceContractClient(new System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding
{
    Security = new System.ServiceModel.WSHttpSecurity
    {
        Mode = System.ServiceModel.SecurityMode.Transport,
        Transport = new System.ServiceModel.HttpTransportSecurity
        {

            ClientCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate
        }
    }
},
new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(new System.Uri("https://myserviceendpoint/webservice.svc")));
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certificate;
```

But it does not work if I don't also have the certificate in my local computer store, I get this error:

[image]

I'm not an expert in security, ssl or certificates, but is this feasible?

All I'm trying to achieve is to ensure that my service is only called by this code, and thought that using self-signed client certificates that are validated in the server would do, but if they need to be in the store it adds unnecessary complexity to the whole thing!

---

### UPDATE 1:

As suggested by Yacoub Massad exporting certificate's Base64 with X509ContentType.Pkcs12 yields exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Key not valid for use in specified state.
```

I'm loading the certificate from store with:

```
    X509Certificate2 certificate = null;
    X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    try
    {
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
        var r = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "LicensingCert", false);
        if (r.Count > 0)
            certificate = r[0];
    }
    catch
    {
        certificate = null;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (store != null)
            store.Close();
    }

    if (certificate == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\tmp\certs\ExportLicensingCert.txt", Convert.ToBase64String(certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12)));
```

### UPDATE 2:

Made sure the certificate had been imported with Mark as exportable and it did the trick, I must have skipped that the first time I imported the certificate. Now testing the compiled code on another computer has stopped doing the error. Thank you so much Yacoub Massad for pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: Do you have the certificate as .cer or .pfx/.p12?

Comment: I have a .cer and a .pfx, but I generated the base64 with the certificate I had in store with the following code: Convert.ToBase64String(certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Cert))

Comment: Certificate Authentication requires the private key. So you need to load the  certificate from a .PFX file.

Comment: Try exporting with `X509ContentType.Pkcs12`

Comment: Exception, replied with Update 1 in question body, as I thought sharing how I retrieve the cert and export it would be useful.

Comment: PFX files need a password. Use an overload of `Export` that takes in a password. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24ww6yzk(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: And use `Certificate.Import` (with a password) to import the PFX into a `X509Certificate2` object. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148440(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Spot on! I did go back and reimport the certificate with the mark exportable checked in, just to make sure, and without the override it did export, don't think I set passwords for the key, do you recommend I do to avoid issues? Also, please add an answer so I can mark it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Did it actually allow you to export the PFX file without a password? Are you going to hardcode the password into the code? Or are you going to ask the user to enter the password?

Comment: Yes. No, Im going to hardcode the certificate base64 in the code.

Comment: It depends on your security requirements. Usually a certificate stored in the local store is a better option.

Comment: Actually now with one of the links you sent me above on how to import, I might consider distriuting the .PFX file and import it to the store. However, side question (let me know if you want me to create another post) isn't serviceCredentials\clientCertificate\authentication@certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" meant to mean the client certificate will only validate if it also exists in the server? I removed it from the store in the server to test a fail, but still worked :(

Comment: No, PeerTrust means that the client certificate needs to be in the trusted people store on the server.

Comment: I only have the root CA in the trusted people store, and it still works, I expected a 403

Comment: Its is better to post a new question and include these and other relevant details.

Comment: FYI, I decided to use a ServiceAuthorizationManager instead of the inbuilt as explained here http://leastprivilege.com/2007/08/26/certificate-based-authentication-and-wcf-mode-independent/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For certificate authentication to work, the client needs the private key to prove its identity to the server. The certificate alone will not work.

Make sure that the `X509Certificate2` that you setup the WCF client to use has a corresponding private key.

You need a PFX file that contains the certificate and the private key and you need to import them into a `X509Certificate2` object via the [`Import`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148440(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: Is this the reason why when importing the client certificate on Windows, the "mark this key as exportable" option needs to be checked?

Comment: @evilmandarine, not necessarily. Even if the key is not exportable, you can still use it. That is, you can use it to authenticate with a service by opening the store and getting the certificate from it. Only if you want to later export the key to a PFX do you check the option you mentioned.